# Where do you tell Heroku to run rails commands with every review app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I deployed a Rails 6 app in Heroku, it deploy but without the database. Then I went to Heroku dashboard, open the console and executed

```
heroku run rails db:prepare
heroku run rails db:seed
```

Which worked. But every review app that generates when I do a pull request in Githut seems to come without the database. If I open the console in the dashboard and run the same commands it works but is there a way to run this commands automatically with every review app?

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to include an `app.json` in your repo, and add a ["postdeploy" script](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-json-schema#scripts) step:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "postdeploy": "bundle exec rails db:prepare db:seed",
  }
}
```

Also to attach a [database addon](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-json-schema#addons) to every Review App, you can have an [environment-specific override](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-json-schema#environments):

e.g. in your `app.json`

```
{
  "environments": {
    "review": {
      "addons": ["heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev"]
    }
  }
}
```